# Monitoring Bing Maps API requests

Tags: azure, monitoring, bing-maps, azureportal

We have setup a Bing Maps API via the Azure Market Place, but I'm trying to understand how I can monitor/report on the requests that are being generated via the Azure Portal (or otherwise). Google has a fantastic interface to facilitate this for the Geolocation API, but I cant seem to find any documentation or work out how you would monitor this for Bing.

I did find this blog https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2012/02/01/bing-maps-reporting-tips/ but it appears out of date and makes no reference to being able to monitor Bing via the Azure Portal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi I think this Microsoft Link might help you out. I have extensive knowledge of the Google Geolocation Service but have not used the Bings Map API yet. But this reference would help me out in your shoes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Bing Maps account/key through the Bing Maps portal (https://www.bingmapsportal.com/) The rich reporting that is mentioned in that blog post is there. If you create Bing Maps key through Azure, all the licensing and reporting is handled by the Azure marketplace which doesn't have rich reports like the Bing Maps portal. The Azure marketplace will email you when your account reaches certain levels to let you know when you are approaching your purchased volume of transactions.